# How do i display a progress bar during a subprocess python

Tags: python

Hi how do i display a progress bar using tqdm while running a subprocess, And instead of displaying the standard update,
Display the progress bar instead until complete?

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def update_system():
    subprocess.Popen( 'sudo apt-get -y update',
               shell=True,
               stdin=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()
    subprocess.Popen( 'sudo apt-get -y upgrade',
               shell=True,
               stdin=subprocess.PIPE ) .communicate()
```

I'm sorry if this post is bad it's my first time posting here.
I basically want to run the above then do something like

```
while update_system = running
      display_progress bar
      until complete
```

Comment: Keep in mind: How would you know what will be updated, the packet-sizes, the ntw-speed to the CDNs etc., etc. in order to estimate the progress of the bar? **The only thing you could do is a spinner IMO..**

Comment: How would i create a spinner for it? that's what i was wondering about load times, and download times.

Comment: In the terminal i also want it displayed instead of the update if possible?

Comment: You need to silent your update: `-qq` -> No output except for errors.. To get the basic idea have a look here and adjust to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234947/spinner-animation-and-echo-command

Comment: Thank you not sure how to replicate in python though

Comment: np ;) Just try and play around a bit, you might also find helpful info on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Follow this post This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429577/showing-progress-while-spawning-and-running-subprocess